# 'Refresh' DynamoDB table in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am creating a lambda function that updates part of an item in DynamoDB and then returns that part of the item. It seems that there is some delay in update_item(), or perhaps updates do not take effect until the end of a function. The value that I am getting in my return never has the update from the function applied. Therefore, is there a way to 'update' the table and apply the changes before returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dumb, pretty obvious, I never queried the table again after my update.

To get the updated item, just run the query for the data again.

```
data = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('primary_key').eq(item_id)
)
```

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer. Please update your answer with a short explanation what you missed and how you solved your problem. You then can even accept your own answer (I think it takes a few days until you are allowed).